# Why is my leap year code not working? (Specially int day)

Tags: c, if-statement, leap-year

Alright so this is a code from Jupyterlab. And i wanted to know why the int day wont respond to the changes made to the value? The code conering starts from line 37 at //day (January).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   
    
    int year = 2021;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 32; 

    //printf("Enter an integer: ");
    //scanf("%d", &year);

    // true if number is less than 0
    //Year
    if (year > 10000 || year < 1) {
        printf("Error: Invalid year, ");
    }else{
        if(year <= 10000 || year >= 1){
            printf("%d, ", year); 
        }
    }
   
    //Month
    if (month > 12 || month < 1) {
        printf("Error: Invalid month\n");
    }else{
    
        if(month <= 12 || month >= 1){
            printf("%d\n", month); 
        }
    }
    //day (January)
    if ((month == 1) && (day > 1 || day < 31)) {
        printf("%d\n", day);
    }else{
        if ((month == 1) && (day < 1 || day > 31)) {
            printf("Error: Invalid day\n");
        }
    }
   
    //Febuary
    if ((year%400 == 0) && (month == 2) && (day > 1 || day < 29)) {
        printf("%d\n", day); 
    }
    if ((year%400 == 0) && (month == 2) && (day < 1 || day > 29)) {
        printf("Error: Invalid day\n");
    }else{
        if ((month == 2) && (day > 1 || day < 28)) {
            printf("%d\n", day);
        }
        if ((month == 2) && (day < 1 || day > 28)) {
            printf("Error: Invalid day\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that from //day (January) the code won't respond to the changes made to the int day? When i enter the date int = 32; it just prints out 32 and not the Error: Invalid day? Why is that and what did i do wrong? [PS. i only have for now January and February...]

Comment: Didn't you post the same code earlier? Lots of the `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: Ask yourself: If `day` is 32 what is the result of `(day > 1 || day < 31)`?

Comment: `(day > 1 || day < 31)` is always true. If the day is more than 31, then `day > 1` is true. If the day is less than 1, `day < 31` is true.

Comment: I pointed out these same problems in your previous question. Why didn't you fix them before reposting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.    You don't need most of the code you show to reproduce your problem; what you show is not minimal.  The second test in the `else` clause of each of the validation stanzas before February is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Because `32` is bigger than `1`. You go right into the if statement on `day > 1`. You need `(day >= 1 && day <= 31)`